# check connection and perform a segue to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, viewdidload

I met strange thing and don't understand why it is not working.

I am using this project to check type of internet connection. My idea was to check connection and jump to login page or stay on first controller if device is not connected.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var connectionTypeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {


        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLogin", sender: self)


    }


    let status = Reach().connectionStatus()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        self.connectionTypeLabel.text = ""

        switch self.status {
        case .unknown, .offline:

            self.connectionTypeLabel.text = "No Connected"

        case .online(.wwan):

            self.connectionTypeLabel.text = "Connected!"

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLogin", sender: self)            
        case .online(.wiFi):

            self.connectionTypeLabel.text = "Connected!"
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLogin", sender: self)        
        }


    }
```

I was trying both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods.

I really dont understand why text label is changing its text correctly and program doesn't go to login view controller.

I created a test button to check if performSegue function is working and it is working just fine. I have no clue why it is not working inside viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move your check to `viewWillAppear`, since `performSegue` wont work correctly on `viewDidLoad` and warp in dispatch time like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02, execute: {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLogin", sender: self)  
})
```

Better approach is dump the vc and move the checking code to `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like:

```
case .online(.wwan), .online(.wiFi):
   let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
   window?.rootViewController = loginVC
   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

For no connection do similar but change `loginVC` with `noConnectionVC`, you will need to give your vc in storyboard an identifier to initialize it in code

Comment: the same story: check is working but performsegue is not

Comment: Are you sure you setup correctly in storyboard? Set breakpoint and see if the segue got called or not

Comment: You can't perform segues in `viewWillAppear` because the view has not appeared yet. It needs to be done in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @MicahWilson works perfect with viewDidAppear! is it a right approach in general? For a second it still shows first controller ... maybe it can be improved ...

Comment: @Tj3n yes, since using button it works fine, I believe storyboard is created correctly. It works good with viewDidAppear ...

Comment: @Almazini In my experience it would work in `viewWillAppear` also, maybe try warp in dispatch time 0.2s and try again, since I know `viewDidAppear` will work but the view will flash for a split second also

Comment: @Tj3n exactly! it works! but looks not so nice as there is a flash.

Comment: @Almazini Also your approach doesn't seems good, since you have that vc do nothing at all, i suggest you check your internet connection in AppDelegate and assign `rootViewController` in there, it would be much cleaner and wont have to deal with segue problem, it never meant to be called early anyway

Comment: @Tj3n maybe you could edit your answer - please add time delay. even with 0.02 it is working but without - not :) and please could you add more details what method should be edited in AppDelegate. And I will mark as correct answer for other people

Comment: @Almazini Edited, feel free to change it as your requirement

Comment: thanks again for helping in figuring out this topic!